# Looping hierarchy in select option using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, loopingselector

I want to make looping in select option using data from database as option. My data is kind of hierarchial data. So if I select one of the option, it will search the value of the selected option in database (search the data that have parentID = the selected value and display select option again) until no data in the database match its search. I've try this one but its too long if make the select option as many as the level I have in that data. Any help will be appreciate

Thank You :)

```
     <select class="form-control" name="chs-org" id="chs-org" style="width:80%"  required="required">
     <option default>Select Organization</option>
      <?php foreach ($org as $org) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $org['ID'];?>"><?php echo $org['Name'];?></option>
         <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <select class="form-control" name="chs-dep" id="chs-dep" style="width:80%;display: none"  required="required">
         <option default>Select</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <div id = "loop0"></div>
         <div id = "loop1"></div>
         <div id = "loop2"></div>
         <div id = "loop3"></div>
         <div id = "loop4"></div>
      <script>
       $('#chs-org').on('change',function(){

var id=$('#chs-org').val();
console.log(id);
   $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url('Hire_4/chs_dep');?>",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{'ID': id},
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data[0]['Name']);
      if (data) {
      $('#chs-dep').show();
      var output = [];
      $.each(data, function(key, value){
        output.push('<option value="'+data[key]['ID'] +'">'+data[key]['Name']+'</option>');
      });
      $('#chs-dep').html(output.join(''));      
            }
          },
        error:function(){
            alert('error ... ');
        }
    });

});
  $('#chs-dep').on('change',function(){ 
var new_id;
var id=$('#chs-dep').val();
id = new_id;
console.log(id);
while(id != ''){
    $.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url('Hire_4/chs_dep');?>",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    data:{'ID': id},
    success:function(data){
      console.log(data);
      if(data) {
          new_id= 0;
          console.log(data.length);
          var output = [];
          output.push('<select name= "chs-div'+(i+1)+'" id="chs-div'+(i+1)+'" class="form-control" style="width:80%;">');
            output.push('<option default>Select</option>');
          $.each(data, function(key, value){
            output.push('<option value="'+data[key]['ID'] +'">'+data[key]['Name']+'</option>');
          });
          output.push('</select>');
          output.push('<br>');
          $('#loop'+i).html(output.join(''));
          var new_id2 = $("#chs-div"+(i+1)).val();
          console.log(new_id2);
          new_id = new_id2;
          id= new_id2;
          $("#chs-div"+(i+1)).on('change',function(){ 
            i=c;
            // console.log(id);
            //console.log(dt);
               //loop();

          });
          i++;

        }
    },
    error:function(){
        alert('error ... ');
    }
}); 

}
 }); 
</script>
```

my controller

```
function chs_dep(){
$ID = $this->input->post('ID');
$where = array('ParentID'=>$ID);
$data = $this->Hire4_model->chs_dep($where);
echo json_encode($data);
}
```

my model

```
public function chs_dep($ID){
$this->db->select('ID,Name');
$this->db->from('dbo.OrganizationTable');
$this->db->where($ID);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Is your `chs-div` change event is the same of `chs-org` and `chs-dep`?

Comment: yes its the same change option

Comment: I posted my answer. You can just copy and test it. Let me know if there's a problem since I can't test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a single `change event`. I changed a lot in your code.

**Code**

```
<div id="chs-container">
    <!-- chs-div Template -->
    <select class="form-control chs-select" id="chs-div-template" style="width:80%; display: none">
        <option default>Select</option>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control chs-select" name="chs-org" id="chs-org" style="width:80%" required="required">
        <option default>Select Organization</option>
        <?php foreach ($org as $org) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $org['ID'];?>"><?php echo $org['Name'];?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <select class="form-control chs-select" name="chs-dep" id="chs-dep" style="width:80%;display: none" required="required">
        <option default>Select</option>
    </select>
    <br>
</div>
<script>
    $('body').on('change', '.chs-select', function(){

        // Get the id dynamically
        //var id = $('#chs-org').val();
        const id = $(this).val();

        const select_id = $(this).attr('id');

        console.log(id);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url('Hire_4/chs_dep');?>",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'ID': id
            },
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                // console.log(data[0]['Name']);

                if (data) {

                    var output = '';

                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        output += '<option value="' + data[key]['ID'] + '">' + data[key]['Name'] + '</option>';
                    });

                    if(select_id == 'chs-org'){
                        // Show the chs-dep
                        $('#chs-dep').show();
                        $('#chs-dep').html(output);

                    }else if(select_id == 'chs-dep'){

                        // Get the template
                        var new_chs_div = $('#chs-div-template').clone();
                        const chs_div_count = i + 1;

                        new_chs_div.attr('name', 'chs-div' + chs_div_count);
                        new_chs_div.attr('id', 'chs-div' + chs_div_count);

                        // Remove the none value.
                        // Just change it to your desire value.
                        new_chs_div.css('display', '');
                        new_chs_div.append(output);

                        //Insert next to the last of .chs-select
                        $('#chs-container').append(new_chs_div);
                        $('#chs-container').append('<br/>');
                        //$(new_chs_div).insertAfter('.chs-select');
                        //$('<br/>').insertAfter('.chs-select');

                    }else if(select_id.includes('chs-div')){
                        // Get the template
                        var new_chs_div = $('#chs-div-template').clone();
                        const chs_div_count = i + 1;

                        new_chs_div.attr('name', 'chs-div' + chs_div_count);
                        new_chs_div.attr('id', 'chs-div' + chs_div_count);

                        // Remove the none value.
                        // Just change it to your desire value.
                        new_chs_div.css('display', '');
                        new_chs_div.append(output);


                        //Insert next to the last of .chs-select
                        $('#chs-container').append(new_chs_div);
                        $('#chs-container').append('<br/>');
                        //$(new_chs_div).insertAfter('.chs-select');
                        //$('<br/>').insertAfter('.chs-select');
                    }

                }
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('error ... ');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: it work until it have no match data, but it makes the #chs-div-template clone 3 times in every select

Comment: $(new_chs_div).insertAfter('.chs-select'); this make the new select was inserted multiple times because the class in every select name contain .chs-select

Comment: @kitcat. Yes, I updated my answer. Just wrap the selects with `<div>` and use the `append` instead. Please try it again.